# Maior valor comparando linhas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou usando **SQL Server 2008 R2** e possuo a seguinte tabela:

```
ID  NUMERO      NOME   MODELO   
--- ----------- ------ -------
1   12          A      777 
2   23          A      777
3   05          A      777        
4   45          B      999  
5   65          C      555
6   30          B      999 
7   67          B      999
8   80          C      555
9   51          C      555
10  03          C      555
```

Gostaria que minha *query* retornasse a seguinte tabela:

```
ID  NUMERO      NOME   MODELO
--- ----------- ------ -------
2   23          A      777
7   67          B      999
8   80          C      555
```

Ou seja, quero que retorne os registros com os maiores valores da coluna NUMERO entre as linhas, independente de quantos registros existir.

Comment: `group by` por modelo, com `subselect` pegando o `max(numero)` ... :)

Comment: Se estiver certa convém colocar la o visto.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que seria algo parecido com isso

```
SELECT A.* FROM Tabela A INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(numero) as numero, nome FROM Tabela GROUP BY nome
) B ON A.nome = B.nome AND A.numero = B.numero ORDER BY nome
```

Abraços

Comment: Isso aí. Eu só substituiria o `nome` por algo com mais garantia de unicidade, como `ID`.

Comment: Eu também, porém eu escrevi em conformidade ao exemplo dele.

Comment: Obrigado!!! Deu certo!

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução:

```
-- código #1
with tabela2 as (
SELECT *, 
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by NOME order by NUMERO desc)
  from tabela
)
SELECT ID, NUMERO, NOME, MODELO
  from tabela2
  where Seq = 1;
```